# I keep getting these emails "Your organization is out of storage space" from SharePoint and can't stop them

Tags: sharepoint, office365, storage, sharepoint-online

The office 365 admins get annoying SharePoint emails telling us we're out of space. We know that and it's not an issue for us, but no matter what I do I can't seem to stop these emails from showing up every single day.
I've even blocked the sender (no-reply@sharepointonline.com) on our email security system, but the emails still come through.
I also looked at every option on SharePoint and O365 admin but no joy.
I've attached a photo of the email as well.

[image: screenshot of the email]

Blocked the emails from our Email Security platform but they still come through.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your frustration. I’m sorry to say that blocking the sender or looking at the SharePoint and O365 admin options will not stop the SharePoint storage limit emails. These emails are sent by the SharePoint Online service itself, and they are not affected by your email security system or your admin settings.

The only way to stop these emails is to either increase the storage limit for your SharePoint site or change the notification threshold to a higher percentage.

Here are the steps:

Go to Active sites in the SharePoint admin center, and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization.

In the left column, select the site, or for a channel site, select the link in the Channel sites column.

On the General tab, under Storage limit, select Edit to open the edit storage limit panel.

Changing the storage limit for a site

Enter the maximum storage in GB for the site.
[image]

Note: For a better user experience, it is recommended to check Allow notifications.

Rererence:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits

Comment: Thank you, Amy. Could you please provide more details on how to increase the notification threshold to a higher percentage?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it out at your convinience.